Unable to run playwright.exe in frozen app built with pyinstaller
My app uses playwright. I am using pyinstaller to build a standalone executable for the python script (--onedir switch used which gives _internal folder with all the dependencies and app.exe).
I do not want to pack the chromium browser along with the app as it would increase the size of the build. Instead, I am calling playwright install chromium to install the browser at runtime if it's not already installed. I am including playwright.exe while I am running pyinstaller with (--add-binary switch). So, playwright.exe is available in the _internal folder.
 playwright_exec = 'playwright'
    if is_running_isolated():
        # get path to playwright.exe residing in _internal folder
        playwright_exec = get_playwright_exec_path()
        log.info(f'Playwright executable path: {playwright_exec}')

        # process = subprocess.Popen(
        #     [playwright_exec, 'install', 'chromium'], 
        #     shell=True, 
        #     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        # )
        # stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        # process.wait()
        process = subprocess.run(
            [playwright_exec, 'install', 'chromium'],
            shell=True,
            capture_output=True,
            text=True)
        log.info(f'Browser install status: {process.returncode}')
        log.info(f'Browser installation console output: {process.stdout}')

        if process.returncode != 0:
           log.error(f'Browser installation console error: {process.stderr}')

The standalone app works and downloads chromium and installs it only if python is installed on the target system. Otherwise, it fails (returncode > 0) but there's nothing in stdout and stderr. I don't even know why it fails.
I have tried running running playwright.exe (which is in _internal folder) manually but it gives an error:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\sourcemachine_user\Desktop\souremaching_folder\venv\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\targetmachine_user\myapp\_internal\playwright.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

